# Filling the gap between different range

Tags: plotting, filling

There are three curves in this figure.

[image]

I use the followed code to fill the gap:

```
Emin = (6)^2 - (wk + 2)^2; Emax1 = (6)^2; Emax2 = (6)^2 - (wk - 2)^2;
p[x_, left_, right_] :=HeavisideTheta[x - left] HeavisideTheta[right - x];
Plot[{Emin p[wk, 0, 4], Emax1 p[wk, 0, 2], Emax2 p[wk, 2, 4]}, {wk, 0, 4}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Pink, White}}, 1 -> {{3}, {Pink, White}}}]
```

Then, I get the figure, which is almost what I want. It would be better if there is no line at the boundary.

How can I fill the gap without the line at the boundary?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
p[x_, left_, right_] := If[left < x < right, 1, Undefined]

Plot[{Emin p[wk, 0, 4], Emax1 p[wk, 0, 2], Emax2 p[wk, 2, 4]}, {wk, 0, 4}, 
      Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Pink}, 1 -> {{3}, Pink}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

You may also use for example the more idiomatic

```
p[x_, left_, right_] := 1 /; left < x < right
```

for the same purpose. What you need is a function that is constant in an interval and has no numeric value outside it, so `Filling` can't act.